# Mongodb поиск $regex

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Не пойму почему не работает.
При формирования запроса в коллекцию пишу следующее:

```
var obj = {
where: {
    tags: {"$in": [/ван.*/i]}
}
News.find(obj.where, .......)
```

Нахожу при этом все записи с поиском по массиву tags по части слова "ван". Все прекрасно работает, но перед поиском мне нужно сделать подобие морфологии, а точнее обрезать части слов.

Для этого я создал функцию в которой буду перерабатывать слова, пока функция выводить только "ван"

```
function morphology(word) {
    var word = "ван";
    return word;
}
```

Изменяю условие в запросе на

```
tags: {"$in": [/morphology(req.params.any).*/i]}  // Где req.params.any = ключевое слова
```

В итоге не одной записи не находит. Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделал так

```
regex = new RegExp(morphology(req.params.any), 'i');

.......
tags: { '$in': {$regex: regex}}
.......
```